# How can Event Dispatch Thread from AWT be started in headless mode?

Tags: java, awt

A bit of background: I have a 3rd party code base that I would like to leave intact. I suspect that by a mistake, one thing that I need from it depends on `SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread` returning true, while the code is in general designed to work as an IDE plugin as well as command line tool.

The command line tool is running in headless mode. What can I do - being able to execute arbitrary code before the `isEventDispatchThread` call is made - to ensure that EDT is running?

Assuming, of course, that it's possible at all.